# Laravel: ErrorException Undefined variable: REQUEST http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert

Tags: laravel

what I'm trying to do is to insert data to database, but its not working, i get this error
:ErrorException Undefined variable: REQUEST http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert

and these are my code
**Controler**

```
    public function insert(Request $request)
{
    $deceased_infos = new deceased_info(); 
    $deceased_infos  ->lastname = $REQUEST->input('dlastname');
    $deceased_infos  ->firstname = $REQUEST->input('dfirstname');
    $deceased_infos  ->middlename = $REQUEST->input('dmiddlename');
    $deceased_infos->save();

    return redirect('/resident')->with('status', "Inserted!!!");   

}
```

**View**

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <form action="{{url('insert')}}" id="deceasedform" method="POST"  class="modal-input">
           {{ csrf_field() }}
           <input type="hidden" name="resident_id" id="resident_id">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-6">......
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('insert',  [ResidentInfoController::class, 'insert']);
```

Comment: Change `$REQUEST` to lowercase since the function param is also lowercase..? `$request`

Comment: $deceased_infos ->lastname = $request->dlastname; change it like this one all the input variable.

Comment: PHP is a case sensitivy language, variables, functions, classes, constants... all of those are case sensitive, meaning $REQUEST is different from $request and $Request and $rEquest and you get the idea.